# Using cURL to get Javascript content

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, curl, grep

I am trying to get the live match commentary from [this link](http://www.espncricinfo.com/india-v-england-2012/engine/current/match/565808.html). I started by getting the HTML content with cURL, and then using grep to parse out the relevant tags/content that I need. However after analyzing the HTML content returned by cURL, I realized that it was all Javascript, and that the content I needed was not in there.

Is there any way that I can get the raw HTML code after the Javascript has executed? Also, I need to be able to run this script from the terminal/bash (since I'm writing this script for GeekTool)?

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the website is storing the data in another HTML file and just displays it in an `<iframe>`: view-source:http://www.espncricinfo.com/netstorage/565808.html

Comment: If you want to have javascript executed, you will need to use a browser, steered by your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [CasperJS](http://kvz.io/blog/2012/11/03/highlevel-testing-with-casperjs/) to run the code and then get everything you want exiting of the page.
Tell me is this is what you were searching or no.